# Vim customization -- .vimrc -- mapping of keys

Tags: vim

Vim customization  --

I have added these lines in my .vimrc

> inoremap /*    /**/< Left >

1. what i intend is, when in press open comments /* -- it should automically print the closing comment.
2. when in comments, what do i add to .vimrc, so that when in comments block at each enter, an "*" is printed at the next line.

   > / *
   >
   > - - /

if i have to add some lines automatically at top of each file i create (in a particular folder) eg - like licenses headers. how to do that. -- *i can think of, making a template file, doing a cp temp.c abc.c and then vi abc.c*. is there any other way.

Comment: and also if it possible i make my cursor "block" from a simple plain "|", it would be easy to locate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters).

```
inoremap <buffer> /*          /**/<Left><Left>
inoremap <buffer> /*<Space>   /*<Space><Space>*/<Left><Left><Left>
inoremap <buffer> /*<CR>      /*<CR>*/<Esc>O
inoremap <buffer> <Leader>/*  /*
```

Comment: what does this do >> inoremap <Leader>/*  /*

Comment: it will map the sequence \/* to the /*. leader means the "\" character.

Comment: By default, anyhow.  `<Leader>` can be changed via `:let mapleader` or other methods.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked on vim.org?

[AutoClose](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2009)

[template file loader](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=198)

[templates.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1172)

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know if anything like was available, i thought people might be using some work around like the one i mentioned. thanks though

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [NerdCommenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218)? It's "a plugin that allows for easy commenting of code for many filetypes", including C and C++ comments.

Answer (score 1):

[thegeekstuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/12/vi-and-vim-autocommand-3-steps-to-add-custom-header-to-your-file/) has a good guide to how to use autocommand to do most of this.  For example add the following to .vimrc (or equivalent) to  add the "*" to new lines in multi-line c-style comments.

```
:autocmd FileType c,cpp
\     comments=sr:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://
```

Comment: autocmd FileType c,cpp,h comments=sr:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://


 > not working

Comment: Hum... I'm using vim and the line in my .vimrc is:

    autocmd FileType c,cpp,h,java  set formatoptions=croql cindent comments=sr:/*,mb:*,el:*/,://

I also have:
    set nocompatible

As the first command which could be causing the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

to address the question from the comments

> and also if it possible i make my cursor "block" from a simple plain "|", it would be easy to locate

```
:help 'guicursor'
```